# How to filter correctly the results of an internal search engine?

Tags: keywords, categories, site-search, keyword-stuffing

Let's say I have a store. The store can have different kind of articles, from phones to clothing. Any user can sell articles on the store (kinda like Ebay).

How can I prevent phones from appearing in the internal search results when someone searches for clothes? Because as any user can sell articles on the store, they could easily post a phone for sale and add start adding tags like "nike" or any other keyword to it that would make their article appear in other unrelated categories.

Is there any technique to prevent this?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution other than the obvious one of moderating the content?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes I am looking for an algorithmic solution or some tool that could help me on this. I didn't know the term 'keyword-stuffing' tho, that might be a good starting point

Comment: Does the internal search engine you're using have the ability to search certain fields and not others? For example, search by category first (plus other layers, like geo), then by exact phrases in the body of the post, and not by tags)?

Comment: I'm planning to use Elasticsearch. It allows you to decide which fields should be indexed. But I'm not sure if it has the ability to detect keyword stuffing

Comment: Elasticsearch is a great search engine. But it's not an "SEO" search engine. You might have to program it in a way to decide what keyword stuffing should mean. Also, I would not go by tags, or by anything that's bound to be abused. Look for categories and long tail or exact phases instead. And make sure you moderate the posts some, to punish the bad actors.